# Does Delphi IBX TIBSQL.ExecQuery has strange transaction requirements (FStreamedActive factor)?

Tags: delphi, firebird

I am using Delphi (2009, never mind) with IBX and I am trying to execute simple code:

```
TestSQL.ExecQuery;
```

Before this code I have checked (and it can be seen in debugger watches as well) that `TestSQL.Transaction.InTransaction` is `True`. Nevertheless the exception is raised:

```
EIBInterBaseError with message 'invalid transaction handle (expecting explicit transaction start)'
```

So, there is no another solution than to execute the code:

```
TestSQL.Transaction.StartTransaction;
TestSQL.ExecQuery;
```

Now the other exception is raised:

```
EIBClientError with message 'Transaction is active'
```

Complete dead end? Delphi has code:

```
procedure TIBTransaction.CheckInTransaction;
begin
  if FStreamedActive and (not InTransaction) then
    Loaded;
  if (FHandle = nil) then
    IBError(ibxeNotInTransaction, [nil]);
end;
```

and it means that the transaction requirement is determined not only by `InTransaction` but by private variable `FStreamedActive` as well. So - the transaction control is way more complex? How can I impact `FStreamedActive`? What is the solution? My test code is part to lengthier code but I wonder how I can break down the inner status of transaction state?

Comment: Are you using Firebird or are you using InterBase?

Comment: Firebird, but I managed to find solution. Now all is working as expected.

Comment: Delphi 2009? hopefully you do not use generics...

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution - `TestSQL.Database` was unintentionally different from `TestSQL.Transaction.DefaultDatabase`. And that manifested in such a strange error message. It is quite strange that IBX allow at all those databases to be different.

Comment: Interbase / Firebird has that mode of using 2-databases transactions, rather exotic more. Also I suspect in IBX terms database==connection. And in Interbase/Firebird practice there is a pattern of opening two connections to the database, one for reading and one for writing. FIB+ supported it AFAIR. And they have the same ancestor as IBX.  Maybe you can backport newer IBX from Lazarus or even try that beta IBX2

Comment: maybe using the wrapper would be helpful to avoid manual (tedious and error-prone) transactions and databases linking. http://loginovprojects.ru/download.php?getfilename=uploads/other/ibxfbutils.zip

Comment: I'm almost certain that I did QC something like that.